# Change city slug on django-cities to only have city name with hyphens

Tags: django

I am using django-cities in my project, and I am stuck at an issue which I can't seem to be able to overcome on my own.

I basically need the slug field of the City model to only list the city name, with hyphens if the name has spaces. This is the standard behaviour of the Country model slug. Instead, the City model returns something like [id]-[city].

So the slug for Country is: United-Arab-Emirates
But the slug for City is: 292968-Abu-Dhabi

I think I've identified where this is generated in django-cities. The BaseCity model has a field slug_contains_id which is set to True, then the slugify method adds it to the slug before the city name:

django-cites.models:

```
   class BaseCity(Place, SlugModel):
    slug_contains_id = True

    name_std = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True, verbose_name="standard name")
    country = models.ForeignKey(swapper.get_model_name('cities', 'Country'),
                                related_name='cities',
                                on_delete=SET_NULL_OR_CASCADE)
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region,
                               null=True,
                               blank=True,
                               related_name='cities',
                               on_delete=SET_NULL_OR_CASCADE)
    subregion = models.ForeignKey(Subregion,
                                  null=True,
                                  blank=True,
                                  related_name='cities',
                                  on_delete=SET_NULL_OR_CASCADE)
    location = PointField()
    population = models.IntegerField()
    elevation = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    kind = models.CharField(max_length=10)  # http://www.geonames.org/export/codes.html
    timezone = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        unique_together = (('country', 'region', 'subregion', 'id', 'name'),)
        verbose_name_plural = "cities"

    @property
    def parent(self):
        return self.region

    def slugify(self):
        if self.id:
            return '{}-{}'.format(self.id, unicode_func(self.name))
        return None
```

But what I'm unable to find out is how to change this default behaviour in the best way to only have the city name as a slug with hyphens if needed, so 292968-Abu-Dhabi will become Abu-Dhabi.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
define slugify:
     return '{}'.format(unicode_func(self.name))
```

Basically i think you are adding `self.id` in the above function which is why it is creating the issue of adding the id.

Comment: Yes that is why it's adding the id, but the issue is that that function comes like that in the django-cities library by default. How can I change this without having to modify the files in the library?

Comment: @Askew then you can try to get the first - and seperate the string by that first -. the second part of the string will be your city